# SSIS - Join tables from different servers whose names are based on a variable

Tags: visual-studio-2010, variables, ssis, oledb

I have a simple query based on tables from two different linked servers. I need both servers to be changeable since we're moving from DEV to UAT to Production. I'm using an expression to set the Connection String and Password for server A. So, using that as a base I set a Data Flow Task and an 'OLE DB Source' to extract the data I need. Ultimately I'd like my query to look like this:

```
Select * from A.Payments p1
Full Outer Join ?.Payments p2 on p1.Id = p2.Id 
where p1.OrderDesc is null or p2.OrderDesc is null
```

Is there a way around it? Can I use a variable or some kind of dynamic query? I haven't managed to parse a project parameter and run one. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

This is done by making the Data Source SQL an expression.

Right click the Data Flow and then click the ellipsis [...] beside "Expressions". In there you will find one of the available properties you can set is the SQLCommand for your Data Flow Source.

It's not the most intuitive thing to be fair.

Comment: Hello Ciaran. Thanks for that. Can you please explain it a bit more though? How can I set the second server name linked to something I can modify easily? I have a series of many Data Flows working on groups of two tables from 2 servers that will be frequently changeable.

Comment: Are you using OLEDB or ADO.NET?